Why js file of report is not deployed in frappe cloud
I’m encountering an issue with the MoM Expenses report in our hosted site. In my local setup, the report filters are being displayed correctly, and the JavaScript (mom_expenses.js) is being parsed. However, the JS is not being parsed on the hosted site (https://site.erpnext.com/api/method/frappe.desk.query_report.get_script), and no filters are visible.
Here are the differences:
Hosted Site Response
{ "message": { "script": "frappe.query_reports['MoM Expenses']={}", "html_format": null, "execution_time": 0.002079, "filters": , "custom_report_name": null } }

Local Setup Response
{"message":{"script":"// Copyright (c) 2024, Nitin Jain and contributors\n// For license information, please see license.txt\n\nfrappe.query_reports["MoM Expenses"] = {\n "filters": [\n {\n "fieldname": "period",\n "label": __("Period"),\n "fieldtype": "Select",\n "options": ["Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly"],\n "default": "Monthly",\n "reqd": 1\n },\n {\n "fieldname": "financial_year",\n "label": __("Financial Year"),\n "fieldtype": "Select",\n "options": get_financial_years(),\n "default": get_default_financial_year(),\n "reqd": 1\n },\n {\n "fieldname": "vendor_name",\n "label": __("Selected Vendor"),\n "fieldtype": "Link",\n "options": "NG 02 Vendor Master", // Link to the correct doctype\n "reqd": 0\n }\n ]\n};\n\n\n// Helper function to generate financial year options\nfunction get_financial_years() {\n const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();\n const financialYears = ;\n for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {\n const startYear = currentYear - i;\n const endYear = startYear + 1;\n financialYears.push(${startYear}-${endYear});\n }\n return financialYears;\n}\n\n// Helper function to get the default financial year\nfunction get_default_financial_year() {\n const currentDate = new Date();\n const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // Months are 0-indexed in JS\n const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();\n\n // If before April, return the previous financial year\n if (currentMonth < 4) {\n return ${currentYear - 1}-${currentYear};\n } else {\n return ${currentYear}-${currentYear + 1};\n }\n}\n\n\n\n//# sourceURL=mom_expenses.js","html_format":null,"execution_time":0,"filters":,"custom_report_name":null}}

It seems like the hosted site is not picking up the full JS file. Any ideas on how to resolve this or what might be causing the script not to load properly on the hosted instance?
Thanks in advance for your help!
What I tried
I verified that the JavaScript file (mom_expenses.js) is correctly placed in the app directory on the local setup, and the filters are displayed as expected.
I checked the hosted site’s response and noticed that the JavaScript is not being parsed, and the filters for the MoM Expenses report are missing.
I also compared the network responses from the hosted site and local setup. The local setup returns the full script, while the hosted site only returns an empty script definition (frappe.query_reports['MoM Expenses'] = {}).
What I expected
I expected the hosted site to behave the same as the local setup, where the full script would be parsed, and the report filters (e.g., Period, Financial Year, Vendor Name) would be visible.
The filters should appear on the report page so that users can interact with them.

Have you tried bench build, clear-cache and running the migrate command on your production site? If the file exists in the app, it could be either a cache invalidation or a symlinking issue - either should be fixed by the aforementioned commands.
